# Securely pass credentials to command-line utility

Tags: bash, shell, security, zsh

```
curl -s 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/{zone_identifier}/logpush/jobs' \
-H "X-Auth-Email: carl@example.com" \
-H "X-Auth-Key: abc123"
```

If I run this, the secret string `abc123` leaks up in three places:

- Shell history
- Terminal output
- `ps` output

I can replace the hardcoded password with something like `$(pass show cloudflare-api-key)`, in which case the password only leaks in `ps` output. This is still bad, as an unprivileged daemon on my machine could steal my credentials.

Is there a handy way to pass credentials to a command-line utility in an ad-hoc fashion such that the credential doesn't leak to `ps` either?

Answer (score 2):

Curl can read flags from stdin, so assuming your password doesn't contain newlines:

```bash
pass show cloudflare-api-key \
  | sed -ne 's/"/\\"/g' -e '1s/.*/-H "X-Auth-Key: &"/p' \
  | curl -K- <other options>
```

Files in `pass` may include other fields below the password, so I made sure that sed only shows the first line. The sed expression is pretty simple: first we escape all of the double quotes inside the password, then we put the password inside curl `-H` option's argument. This can be easily extended to pull other fields, like email, from `pass` as well:

```
$ printf %s\\n '12"3' 'email: foo@bar.com' \
  | sed -ne 's/"/\\"/g' -e '1s/.*/-H "X-Auth-Key: &"/p' -e 's/^email: \(.*\)/-H "X-Auth-Email: \1"/p'
-H "X-Auth-Key: 12\"3"
-H "X-Auth-Email: foo@bar.com"
```

Comment: Side note: while this approach is somewhat more secure than passing the password as an argument, or an environment variable, nothing usually stops an evil unprivileged daemon from putting a keylogger inside your `~/.bashrc` and stealing the gpg password of your password store that way.